# What Debian packages are needed to build Emacs from source?

Tags: build, debian

I know that I can run `sudo apt-get install emacs25`, but (for reasons I don't want to get into) I want to build Emacs from source.

In the past, in order to do this, I've had to `apt-get install` Debian packages required to build Emacs, but this time I cannot find any up-to-date and authoritative list of what those packages are for the latest version of Emacs.

Any information on this would be appreciated.

---

FWIW, the following (based on the `INSTALL` file included with the Emacs source) failed immediately:

```
% apt-get build-dep emacs25
Reading package lists... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for emacs25
```

---

EDIT: Below is what I have in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb       http://http.us.debian.org/debian                 stretch           main   contrib   non-free
deb-src   http://http.us.debian.org/debian                 stretch           main   contrib   non-free

deb       http://http.us.debian.org/debian                 stretch-updates   main   contrib   non-free
deb-src   http://http.us.debian.org/debian                 stretch-updates   main   contrib   non-free

deb       http://security.debian.org/                      stretch/updates   main   contrib   non-free
deb-src   http://security.debian.org/                      stretch/updates   main   contrib   non-free
```

Comment: Do you have `deb-src` in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158395/apt-get-build-dep-is-unable-to-find-a-source-package

Comment: @npostavs: Yes, thanks (I've updated my answer to address your comment)

Comment: Huh. Well I suppose the build-dep command would give you the same as what's listed at https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch/emacs25

Comment: Note that the particular packages required depend on *how* you build Emacs. Are you enabling or disabling any of the configure options? If so, give us details.